# trying to remove all items and add incoming items from a nested redux object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

I have below reducer and below initial State. classinfo is the parent state which has a nested state array of students. with the below reducer I am planning (replace previous students with new students ) to delete all students from the previous state, add new students from "action.data.students" and return a new state. first time I add students there is no issue, when I add another student I am getting the error 
"A state mutation was detected between dispatches" 
please let me know, where I am doing it wrong.

`classInfo[
{
Id:"",
students:[]
}]`

```
function sampleReducer(state = initialState.classInfo, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_CLASSROOMS:
      return [...state, ...action.data];
    case types.REMOVE_CLASSROOMS:
      return state.filter((class) => class.id !== action.data);
    case types.ADD_STUDENT_DETAILS:
      const stateObj = state.map((class, i) => {
        if (class.id === action.data.id) {
          return {
            ...class,
            students: {
              ...action.data.students,
            },
          };
        }
        return {
          ...class,
        };


      });
      return stateObj;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing great, `do not to mutate the state` simply means, do not alter the `prevState` just update the state.

The main error is that, you are trying to change state of student as previously it was `array` type and while you are updating it you made it as `object` type just a typo. *please use [ ] instead of { }*

```js
const state = {
  id: 1,
  students: [
    {first: 1},
    {second: 2},
    {third: 3}
  ]
}

const action = {
  data: {
    students: [
      {fourth: 4}
    ]
  }
}

const updatedStudents = {
  ...action.data.students
}

console.log(state);
console.log(updatedStudents);
```

So, in your case->

```
case types.ADD_STUDENT_DETAILS:
      const stateObj = state.map((class, i) => {
        if (class.id === action.data.id) {
          return {
            ...class,
            students: [
              ...action.data.students,
            ],
          };
        }
        return {
          ...class,
        };


      });
      return stateObj;
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like I missed "[ ]".

Answer (score 1):

You are spreading object for `students`. It's an array. So use square brackets and spread the students array -  `students: [...action.data.students]`

```js
...
case types.ADD_STUDENT_DETAILS:
      const stateObj = state.map((class, i) => {
        if (class.id === action.data.id) {
          return {
            ...class,
            students: [ //<----use square brackets(as its an array)
              ...action.data.students
            ],
          };
        }
        return class;


      });
      return stateObj;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I just missed "[ ]"